# Idle timeout defined by CommonChannelConfigKeys

Tags: netflix-zuul

We are using netflix-zuul 2.1.6 and we are using ribbons and we are not using eureka. In our config we have something like:

```
myclient.ribbon.listOfServers=xxx
myclient.ribbon.ReadTimeout=90000
myclient.ribbon.ConnectTimeout=90000
```

We noticed that we were getting a timeout at 65 seconds even though we have timeout set at 90 seconds. We eventually trace this down to BaseZuulChannelInitializer.addTimeoutHandler doing:

```
    pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, idleTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

where idleTimeout is the value from CommonChannelConfigKeys.idleTimeout

Is there any way to override this value through configuration?

Regards,
LT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arthur Gonigberg from Netflix Zuul github project gave me the answer. It can be overriden using this property:
server.connection.idle.timeout